# Electron forge - Windows build - app-update.yml is missing

Tags: electron, electron-forge

Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VitalEngine Desktop\app-6.0.0\resources\app-update.yml'

The file must be created

Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VitalEngine Desktop\app-6.0.0\resources\app-update.yml'

The file must be created
Error: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\Program Files (x86)\VitalEngine Desktop\app-6.0.0\resources\app-update.yml'

The file must be created